# Cannot read menu of undefined Stack Template pixinvent

Tags: angularjs

I use stack template from PIXINVENT,
In the Sidebar Menu sometimes it works and expands to show childs menu and sometimes i get cannot read menu of undefined, I believe that the problem is async issue (something loading before another.
In the sidebar.ts in ngOninit() there are two lines:

```
$.getScript('./assets/app/js/core/app.js');
$.getScript('./assets/app/js/core/app-menu.js');
```

The app.js has $.app and uses menu property $.app.menu and the problem is that sometimes i get cannot read menu of undefined.

any help?

Comment: tag #angularjs not #angular

Comment: The title should let immediately understand what's the issue you are exposing, try being more precise

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, The problem is the $.getScript() works async and one executes before another and causing a problem,
The solution is replacing $.getScript() by :

```
$.ajax({
        url: './assets/app/js/core/app.js',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'script',
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: './assets/app/js/core/app-menu.js',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'script',
      });
```